# How to make the background of a Bar chart transparent using CSS?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-animate

I want to implement the design of a bar chart where the background will be transparent but the border will be colored. To make things clear this is what I'm trying to achieve:

Background transparent:

[image]

I have tried to implement the design on my side but whenever I tried to make the background transparent everything goes transparent including the border.

This is my bar chart so far:

[image]

In case you want to help out. This is my code:

```
<div class="col-md-4 progress skill-bar">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow='70' aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"  style="background-color: yellow">
        <span class="skill" id="content"></span>
    </div>                
</div>
```

This is my css:

```
<style type="text/css">

.progress {
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 400px;

}
.progress .skill {
  font: normal 12px "Open Sans Web";
  line-height: 35px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 0 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.progress .skill .val {
  float: right;
  font-style: normal;
  margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}

.progress-bar {
  text-align: left;
  transition-duration: 3s;
}
</style>
```

please, how can I achieve the transparent effect? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is the Bootstrap progressbar

```
.progress {
    background: transparent; // add this line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your backgournd-color to transparent and add a border.

```
.progress{
   background: transparent;
   border: 2px solid black; // the color you want the chart to be
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your background to transparent and border colour.

```
.progress { 
     background: transparent; 
     border-color:black;
 }
```